# AngularJS comparing $viewValue against ng-model or object param

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dynamic form that utilizes ng-min/ng-max for validation.  My ng-max & ng-min are bound to object parameters modelParam.maxvalue and modelParam.minvalue, respectively.  My requirement is to display some alert or error if the value entered in my form field exceeds ng-max or falls belows ng-min.  Quite simple in that regard.  I tried doing this with $viewValue, but it did not quite work out as planned.

My form:

```
<form name="modelParamsForm" novalidate>    

<div class="form-group col-md-4" ng-repeat="modelParam in modelParams" ng-
class="{ 'has-error' : modelParamsFieldForm.value.$invalid }">

   <ng-form name="modelParamsFieldForm">

        <label class="col-md-5">{{ modelParam.paramname }}</label>              
        <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm col-md-5" ng-
        model="modelParam.value" name="value" ng-min="modelParam.minvalue" 
        ng-max="modelParam.maxvalue" required style="maxhight: 20px">
        <span ng-show="modelParamsFieldForm.value.$invalid"></span> 
        <span ng-if="$viewValue > modelParam.maxvalue">Error message</span>
        <span ng-if="$viewValue < modelParam.minvalue">Error message</span>

    </ng-form>
</div>
...
```

My controller is pretty standard...

```
$scope.modelParams = {};
$scope.loadModelParams = function(modelName) {
        var req = {
                method : 'GET',
                url : urlPrefix + 'PB_OPTIMISER_GET_MODEL_PARAMS',
                params: {modelName : modelName}         
            };
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http(req).then(function(response) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.modelParams = response.data;
            $scope.modelParamsOld = angular.copy($scope.modelParams);
        }, function() {
            $scope.loading = false;
        });

    };
```

Obviously, I made some error with

```
<span ng-if="$viewValue > modelParam.maxvalue">Error message</span>
<span ng-if="$viewValue < modelParam.minvalue">Error message</span>
```

I am sure it arises from my misunderstanding of how exactly to use $viewValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the $viewValue is for a particular ngModel instance. Its not a generic value.  For example if you had multiple inputs, each would have its own $viewValue. Therefore in the span element you need to specify which ngModel you are referring to. An easy way to do this in the view itself is to use the name attributes of the form and input field. Also remember that in the case of an input, the $viewValue is a string, so when comparing it to min and max value, you need to use its length property. Take a look at the updated code to reflect these changes:

```
<ng-form name="modelParamsFieldForm">
    <label class="col-md-5">{{ modelParam.paramname }}</label>              
    <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm col-md-5" ng-
        model="modelParam.value" name="value" ng-min="modelParam.minvalue" 
        ng-max="modelParam.maxvalue" required style="maxhight: 20px">
    <span ng-show="modelParamsFieldForm.value.$invalid"></span> 
    <span ng-if="modelParamsFieldForm.value.$viewValue.length > modelParam.maxvalue">Error message</span>
    <span ng-if="modelParamsFieldForm.value.$viewValue.length < modelParam.minvalue">Error message</span>
</ng-form>
```

**UPDATE**

jsfiddle with a working example: **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/up2qxcxe/)**

Comment: It worked!  For some reason it accepted "modelParamsFieldForm.value.$viewValue" but not "...$veiwValue.length"  Is this because modelParam.minvalue is an integer?

Comment: Are you sure, because it should only really work with $viewValue.length because its comparing with an integer. The length property returns an integer. If you dont include the length within the if statement, then it'll trigger the minvalue warning after a single character and then after 2 or more, it'll always show the max value warning. Without the .length property it's just comparing a string to an integer

Comment: You are right!  When .length property is not added it checks the value against each integer, BUT when I add .length my error message no longer appears :/

Comment: what does your controller look like? Atleast the section where you defined the modelParam

Comment: I have updated my question with my controller code, $scope.modelParams is just an associative array of objects modelParams = [{model: "MAF", paramname: "CascDefaultSpreadOverride", minvalue: "0", maxvalue: "100",…},…]

Comment: Ok at this point, its best to try and see the difference between your code and a sample working one with the same code functionality. I've updated my answer to include a jsfiddle with a working example using your code as a template. Take a look at it and see where you might be missing something on your end. Confirm that your loadModelParams function is correctly fetching the values.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it is obviously correct.  I even made my own version with static JSON on JSfiddle, but on my actual application it does not work...very strange.  Thanks.

Comment: I think I found the problem!  In my JSON modelParam.maxvalue is a type string, i.e. maxvalue : "1000".  So, I was trying to compare a number with length() with a string!  Do I have to parse maxvalue?  But how would I do this in the directive?

Comment: That makes sense. You wouldnt have to do anything in the directive, when you declare the `modelParam`, just set it to an integer (without any quotes). `$scope.modelParam = { ..., maxValue : 10, minValue: 3, ...}`

Comment: When you say set it to integer, you mean table constraints in the db right...?  Unfortunately I don't have access to data source...it's some Java Spring app...

Comment: I see, if you dont want to mess with the source data, and assuming its in string when you get the json object. The simplest solution is to have another 2 variables as the integer representaion of the min and max value and then reference that in the directive, so in the controller you could have something like: `$scope.mpMaxValue = parseInt($scope.modelParams.maxValue)`. Then just reference `mpMaxValue` in the directives instead of  the modelParams.maxValue

Comment: Yeah, I got the backend devs to send it to me as int.  Works now!  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad to see its fixed.