# Angularjs $viewValue.length for form validation

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have a simple from to which I am trying to add validation.  I am comparing the $viewValue in the form with the value of ng-min/mg-max to notify the user if he is trying to enter values that are over the max and under the min allowed.  The issue is that if I use ng-if="myform.$viewValue.length > maxvalue" the error does not appear.  However, the error DOES appear when I exclude .length() However, in this case it is checking every integer in of $viewValue string with maxvalue number, which is not intended.  I understand that $viewValue.length would give me a number instead of a string so that I may compare a number with a number, but in this case the error never appears.

I even have a JSFiddle example that works https://jsfiddle.net/up2qxcxe/
But it does not in my app.

Here is my form:

```
    <form name="modelParamsForm" novalidate>    
      <div class ="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4" ng-repeat="modelParam in 
          modelParams" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : 
          modelParamsFieldForm.value.$invalid }">
              <ng-form name="modelParamsFieldForm">           
                 <label form-group>{{modelParam.label}}</label>                     
                 <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" 
                 ng-model="modelParam.value" name="value" 
                 ng-min="modelParam.minvalue" ng-max="modelParam.maxvalue" >                    
                 <span ng-show="modelParamsFieldForm.value.$invalid"></span>
                 //MIN-MAX VALIDATOR
                 <div ng-if="modelParamsFieldForm.value.$viewValue.length > 
                 modelParam.maxvalue">Max exceeded:{{modelParam.maxvalue}}
                 </div> 
              </ng-form>
        </div>
     </div>
```

My controller is nothing special:

```
$scope.modelParams = {};
$scope.loadModelParams = function(modelName) {
        var req = {
                method : 'GET',
                url : urlPrefix + 'PB_OPTIMISER_GET_MODEL_PARAMS',
                params: {modelName : modelName}         
            };
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http(req).then(function(response) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.modelParams = response.data;
            $scope.modelParamsOld = angular.copy($scope.modelParams);
        }, function() {
            $scope.loading = false;
        });

    };
```

EDIT: In my JSON modelParam.maxvalue is a string.  I think the problem was that I am comparing a myform.$viewValue.length with modelParam.maxvalue which is string type.  I am not sure how to get around this...do I have to parse maxvalue?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need $viewValue.  Your `ng-if`s are wrong.  Change to

```
        <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm col-md-5" ng-model="modelParam.value" name="test" min="modelParam.minvalue"  max="modelParam.maxvalue">

    <span ng-if="modelParam.value > modelParam.maxvalue">Too Many!!</span><br>
    <span ng-if="modelParam.value  < modelParam.minvalue">Too Few!!</span>
```

It should work fine.  Here is your [Plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/84m0meaf/) working the way I think you want.

Comment: Well, I just learned that modelParam.maxvalue is type string.  So I need to compare the value displayed in the form field, not modelParam.value.  I am trying to warn the user if he types a value above maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the modelParam.maxvalue was coming from the database as a string, rather than integer.  So when comparing `ng-if="myform.$viewValue.length > modelParam.maxvalue"` I was comparing an integer with a string, and that obviously did not produce the desired results.  The solution was to go to the table and make maxvalue an integer.

Alternatively one can have a second variable for maxvalue in the controller that parses the string like so: `$scope.mpMaxValue = parseInt($scope.modelParams.maxValue)`

See this post for a longer discussion: [AngularJS comparing $viewValue against ng-model or object param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594667/angularjs-comparing-viewvalue-against-ng-model-or-object-param/43595059?noredirect=1#comment74382988_43595059)